# Is it true that mysql database can only process a simple query at same time?

Tags: mysql

If I have a few different `threads` (in `Java`) query different tables in the same MySQL database. Can the database process multiple query at the same time?

If so, how can I optimize this issue: I have several tasks (in `Java` and need to query `MySQL database`), how can I finish them using less time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the engine you use. For `InnoDB` `MySQL` performs `row-level` lock only for writes. For `MyIsam`, `MEMORY` and `MERGE` there are `table-level` locks which are granted for reading.

Source http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-locking.html.

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_row_lock

Answer (score 0):

YES ofcourse...Or else there wouldn't be such thing called table lock